# Update AD tsprofilepath and append string to variable in path name

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to bulk update the “terminalservicesprofilepath” attribute for several ad user objects and append a variable + string at the end of the path.  So far this is what I have, which fails miserably.

```
$users = (gc C:\Scripts\users.txt |%{get-aduser $_ })
FOREACH ($user in $users){
$profiledir = $user + ".DOMAIN.V2"
$x = [ADSI]”LDAP://$($user.DistinguishedName)”
$x.psbase.invokeset(“terminalservicesprofilepath”,”\\Fileserver\tsprofile\$profiledir”)
}
```

Comment: Answered my own question if anyone is interested or needs this in the future

Answer (score 0):

```
$users = (gc C:\SCRIPTS\test.txt |%{get-aduser $_ })
FOREACH ($user in $users){
$profiledir = $($user.samaccountname) + '.DOMAIN.V2'
$tsppath = "\\FILESERVER\$profiledir"
$x = [ADSI]”LDAP://$($user.DistinguishedName)”
$x.psbase.invokeset(“terminalservicesprofilepath”,”$tsppath”)
$x.setinfo()
}
```